# SSRS display a column horizontaly

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a month table with month names and month number. How can I display my month table like this (4 months in a row) ?

[image: Month table]

Comment: What does your source data look like? I think the solution would likely be better in SQL, rather than in SSRS. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the intention of this table? I assume that's not the final result or you could just add a table and type them in. You could do this in SSRS (I you must) but without knowing the context its hard to give an answer that will be of any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is like so

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (MonthNum INT, [MonthName] NVARCHAR(20))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (MonthNum, [MonthName])
VALUES
    (1, 'January'),
    (2, 'February'),
    (3, 'March'),
    (4, 'April'),
    (5, 'May'),
    (6, 'June'),
    (7, 'July'),
    (8, 'August'),
    (9, 'September'),
    (10, 'October'),
    (11, 'November'),
    (12, 'December')
;
```

I would attempt the solution in TSQL

Create some columns to tally with the order you want the months names to appear in, I'll use a CTE here

```
;WITH cte(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
AS(
    SELECT 1, 4, 7, 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 5, 8, 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 6, 9, 12
)
```

Join the Table of months

```
;WITH cte(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
AS(
    SELECT 1, 4, 7, 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 5, 8, 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 6, 9, 12
)
SELECT
      T1.[MonthName]
    , T2.[MonthName]
    , T3.[MonthName]
    , T4.[MonthName]
FROM 
    cte     X
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T1.MonthNum = X.Col1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 T2 ON T2.MonthNum = X.Col2
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 T3 ON T3.MonthNum = X.Col3
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table1 T4 ON T4.MonthNum = X.Col4
```

to get this

```
MonthName   MonthName   MonthName   MonthName
January     April       July        October
February    May         August      November
March       June        September   December
```

Comment: Thanks, but i would rather do it with the design view.

Comment: Why not create a new dataset with the query and use it that way?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the only way to do it.